# How to access Unit Cell Dimensions inside tclForces Script (NAMD)?

Tags: periodic-boundary-conditions, namd

I have a NAMD system with PBCs (FlexibleCell on) and I need to access the unit cell information to manually apply wrapping to some atoms in the system such that i may apply custom restraints to them.

How can i access this information ? (not sure why tclForces doesn't have a wrap function built in like tclBC does).